# Query not using index when it should

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.5

I have this query (below) which keeps hitting the table when it should be using the `created` index.  Is there something simple I'm missing here?  How can I get it to use the index instead of the table?

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.27-log |
+------------+

    mysql> explain SELECT `Lead`.`subid` AS `subid` FROM `leads` AS `Lead` WHERE `Lead`.`is_live` = '1' AND `Lead`.`created` >= '2012-12-13 00:00:00' AND `Lead`.`created` <= '2012-12-13 23:59:59' AND NOT (`Lead`.`subid` IS NULL) GROUP BY `Lead`.`subid`;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Lead  | range | is_live,subid,created | created | 8       | NULL | 86390 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Indexes:

```
    mysql> show indexes from leads;
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| leads |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id              | A         |     2375473 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | id              |            1 | id              | A         |     2375473 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | client_id       |            1 | client_id       | A         |         559 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | is_live         |            1 | is_live         | A         |         444 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | sold            |            1 | sold            | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | amount          |            1 | amount          | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | subid           |            1 | subid           | A         |         587 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | client_url      |            1 | client_url      | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | originating_url |            1 | originating_url | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | ping_id         |            1 | ping_id         | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | network_id      |            1 | network_id      | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | group_id        |            1 | group_id        | A         |         565 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | is_completed    |            1 | is_completed    | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | uid             |            1 | uid             | A         |     2375473 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | redirected      |            1 | redirected      | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | created         |            1 | created         | A         |     2375473 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | first_name      |            1 | first_name      | A         |      339353 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | last_name       |            1 | last_name       | A         |       2375473 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| leads |          1 | email           |            1 | email           | A         |     2375473 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
19 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `leads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_ip` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `loan_amount` char(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salutation` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `alternate_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` datetime NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `phone_home` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `phone_work` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `phone_work_extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `is_military` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `drivers_license_state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `drivers_license_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `residence_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `own_home` char(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `months_at_address` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `years_at_address` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthly_residence_cost` double(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `income_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `occupation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pay_per_period` double(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `monthly_income` double(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `pay_frequency` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pay_day1` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pay_day2` datetime NOT NULL,
  `employer_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `employer_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employer_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employer_state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employer_zip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `years_employed` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `months_employed` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hire_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `subid` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mother_maiden_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ping_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lead_mgmt` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'This field defines if we sent this lead to primelead or not\n  not.',
  `supervisor_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `supervisor_phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `supervisor_phone_ext` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `bank` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bank_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `months_at_bank` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `bank_routing_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `bank_account_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `bank_account_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `direct_deposit` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `referer_first_name1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_last_name1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_phone1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_relation1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_first_name2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_last_name2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_phone2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_relation2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_first_name3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_last_name3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_phone3` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer_relation3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_time` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_optin` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_profile` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_balance1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_interest_rate1` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_rate_type1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_balance2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_interest_rate2` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_rate_type2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthly_debt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_loan_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mortgage_preferred_loan_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `existing_property_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_property_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `down_payment` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_found` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pawn_transaction_type` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pawn_has_item` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pawn_will_sell` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pawn_nplanet_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pawn_how_soon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bankruptcy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loan_purpose` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_at_work` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplemental_income` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lic_plate` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_make` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_miles` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_model` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_type` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_vin` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_check_auth` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fico_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `co_signer_available` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt_in` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forward_application` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marital_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originating_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_live` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sold` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `network_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_data` text,
  `redirect_url` text,
  `redirected` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `is_completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `lead_response` text,
  `r_response` text,
  `resubmitted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `param_type` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
```

Primary Key and indexes:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `is_live` (`is_live`),
  KEY `sold` (`sold`),
  KEY `amount` (`amount`),
  KEY `subid` (`subid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `client_url` (`client_url`),
  KEY `originating_url` (`originating_url`),
  KEY `ping_id` (`ping_id`),
  KEY `network_id` (`network_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `is_completed` (`is_completed`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `redirected` (`redirected`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `first_name` (`first_name`),
  KEY `last_name` (`last_name`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `subid_islive_created_ndx` (`subid`,`is_live`,`created`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `islive_subid_created_ndx` (`is_live`,`subid`,`created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
  AUTO_INCREMENT=2217258 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
  ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC 
  COMMENT='table to store leads'
```

Comment: Wow, that's lost of indexes on a table. How many columns does it have? I imagine the optimizer has lost its mind...

Comment: Heh. Yea, the table has 135 fields and about 2MM records in it.

Comment: Wow, that leads table needs mad normailzation.

Comment: Yes, typically I would, but the way this application runs, it's much faster/easier denormalized in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has to use the table and not the index alone because you have two columns (`is_live` and `sub_id`) in the `WHERE` clause that are not part of this (`created`) index. The `sub_id` column is also included in the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT` list so how would it be possible for the table not to be used?

---

I would try an index that "covers" the query, like the `(is_live, created, subid)` and writing the query like this:

```
SELECT subid 
FROM leads
WHERE is_live = 1
  AND created >= '2012-12-13 00:00:00' 
  AND created <= '2012-12-13 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY subid 
HAVING subid IS NOT NULL ;
```

or the index `(is_live, subid, created)` and the query written like:

```
SELECT subid 
FROM 
    ( SELECT subid
      FROM leads
      WHERE is_live = 1
      GROUP BY is_live, subid
    ) AS d
WHERE subid IS NOT NULL
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM leads l 
        WHERE l.is_live = 1
          AND l.subid = d.subid
          AND l.created >= '2012-12-13 00:00:00' 
          AND l.created <= '2012-12-13 23:59:59'
      ) ;
```

Comment: I tried that with "create unique index created_subid_islive_ndx on leads (created, subid, is_live);" and then re-ran both mine and your query and it didn't seem to change a thing other than adding the index to the possible_keys explain column (in my query), and removing the subid from possible_keys (in your query).

Comment: Did you try the indexes I suggested?

Comment: I didn't, and now I see after doing a bit of reading that the order makes a difference.  I'll give that a shot and let you know.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't change anything.  
`| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                            | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Lead  | range | is_live,created,islive_subid_created_ndx | created | 8       | NULL | 86390 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |`

Comment: `subid_islive_created_ndx` = subid, is_live, created .... and ...
`islive_subid_created_ndx` = is_live, subid, created

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE leads ;`

Comment: Done. Please take a look and let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you ypercube!  That works, and is much faster. I appreciate all your time and assistance.